# angular2 - loading app into a router-outet i.e. using router-outlet on index.html

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**index.html**

```
<body><router-outlet><p>loading...</p></router-outlet></body>
```

I am trying to load the application into the router-outlet in index.html.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent }from './home/welcome/header.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent }from ./home/common/page_not_found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
       path : 'home',
       component : HomeComponent,
       children: [
        {
            path: 'welcome',
            component: HeaderComponent,
            outlet: 'home_content'
        }
      ]
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) 
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HeaderComponent }  from './home/welcome/header.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './home/common/page_not_found.component';

@NgModule({
   imports:        [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],          
   declarations:   [ HomeComponent, HeaderComponent, PageNotFoundComponent ],
   bootstrap:      [ HomeComponent  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: '[router-outlet]',
  templateUrl: './home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent  { }
```

**home.html**

```
<p>This is Home-HTML</p>
<router-outlet name="home_content"></router-outlet>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: '[router-outlet]',
  templateUrl: './header_view.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent  { 
    welcome_message = "Hello there...";
}
```

**header_view.html**

```
<p>This is Header_View-HTML</p>
```

The page shows the "loading..." message from index.html but does not load the application.
I am getting following error in browser console.

```
HomeComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: The selector "[router-outlet]" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (dom_renderer.ts:234)
at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (services.ts:984)
at createElement (element.ts:199)
at createViewNodes (view.ts:307)
at createRootView (view.ts:225)
at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:815)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (services.ts:140)
at ComponentFactory_.create (refs.ts:130)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (component_factory_resolver.ts:112)
at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (application_ref.ts:670)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's wrong to use router-outlet as selector, change your selector to other an name:
you can create the app component (the component you will bootstrap in your module) use a selector like "app-root"

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 })
```

your index.html will be like this:

```
...<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>...
```

then you can add  inside your app.component.html like this:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

router-outlet will serve components based on routes inside your routes.ts.

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashoardComponent }
```

Comment: i need to load a screen (say, home view) into the router-outlet in index.html and once after the user logs in, i need to completely replace the entire html in place of home view with another (say, dashboard view). 

it's wrong to use router-outlet as selector
=> if so, please tell me how to provide the selector.

I provide : selector: '[home_modules]' in component.ts and <router-outlet name="home_modules"></router-outlet> in html and outlet: 'home_modules' in routing.module.ts, but then I am not able to load different screens.

Comment: I believe, we cannot give the same selector name to multiple components. So, how do I achieve this. <router-outlet home_modules></router-outlet> in html and selector: '[home_modules]' when provided in two components which are to be loaded in the same router-outlet, shoots error : "More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.".